# How to make a class initializable with both positional and keyword arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, arguments

I am trying to make a class which allows for initalization with either default values for arguments, or with the values passed to it. Furthermore, I want to be able to pass those arguments either as positional or as keyworded ones. It works with keyworded arguments, however, when I try creating it like `foo = Foo(3)` with any number of positional arguments provided I get a `TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        args_list = OrderedDict()
        args_list.update(x=1,
                        y=2,
                        z=3)
        args_list.update(kwargs)

        iter_args_list = enumerate(args_list)
        for positional_arg in args:
            (_, key_value) = next(iter_args_list)
            args_list[key_value] = positional_arg

        for argument_key, argument_value in args_list.items():
          setattr(self, argument_key, argument_value)
```

Comment: What type error do you get? Please provide a full traceback.

Comment: `TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`, edited the main post

Comment: for future reference: always include the error message (and the traceback). Obviously there was an error (otherwise you would not ask a question), but it helps to show what error you got.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is probably that you pass the `args` and `kwargs` to the `super()` and `object` does not like that since the `object` does not take (named or unnamed) parameters. So you should rewrite:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # ...
```

to:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        # ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, unfortunately it didn't seem to help

Comment: @Cons: edit your question with the new error and a *full* traceback.

Comment: @Cons: I think `Foo` has a superclass that you do not share. As a result, it is impossible to debug this, since you make a `super().__init__` call, and thus we need at least the signature of that function.

Comment: Oh my mistake, it actually did work. The problem now is how I actually assign the parameters. It fails to work with keywords longer than 1 char long, but I guess it's a separate issue

Comment: @Cons: can you provide the error you get? I managed to construct a `Foo(ab=2)`.

Comment: The problem was in `args_list[key_value[0]] = positional_arg`, it should be `args_list[key_value] = positional_arg` instead.  Also, it turns out that OrderedDict does not preserve the order of arguments passed within one `update()` call, which leads to not-obvious ordering in positional arguments assignment, which in turn defeats the purpose of this code

Comment: @Cons: we `kwargs` is a vanilla dictionary, so no order is preserved. Unfortunately I don't see an easy workaround. You can `update` the keys one at a time, or pass a list of tuples like `args_list.update([('x',1),('y',2),('z',3)])`.